# What is the difference between String and nvarchar(5000) in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, string, nvarchar

I am doing my first database project in PostgreSQL or Oracle.

I would like to get an answer for my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there's no string in database. string in .net is limited only by memory. 
there's no such thing as nvarchar(5000). you can have nvarchar(4000) or nvarchar(max)
4000 is the max char length you can store and one char is store in 2 bytes. 
you can read more about this in [Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx)

Comment: to add to this, nvarchar stores the data in "national" unicode, whereas a varchar uses the database defined encoding and is generally half the size to store

Comment: @curtisk: Which one does SO use?

Comment: @Masi: You might be interested in "What was Stack Overflow built with?" http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/